# Anyone know how to get nicescroll plugin to work horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scrollbar

I found this awesome plugin https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll that turns the scrollbar into one that is styled similar to OSX scrollbars.

Unfortunately it only works vertically. I was wondering if anyone figured out how to make this work horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use that library in particular ? You can checkout [iScroll javascript library](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll